# What are some different uses of く?

Tags: reading-comprehension

I know the basic use for adverbs, but I found this sentence

> 飛行機が飛ばなくなると、地方の経済が悪くなるかもしれません

and I just don't understand the く in 飛ぶ.

Answer (score 2):

You can think of it essentially the same way as with adjectives.  The base word is simply 飛ばない which conjugates the way an イ-adj does.  So 飛ばなくなる means "become such that they don't fly", or more simply "stop flying".

> 飛行機が飛ばなくなると、地方の経済が悪くなるかもしれません　→　If the plane(s) stop flying, the local economy may take a turn for the worse.

Comment: Thanks it makes sense now